# HDInsight Storm cannot read/write to EventHubs using sample application

Tags: java, azure, apache-storm, azure-hdinsight, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to implement the sample EventHub application given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-storm-develop-java-event-hub-topology), but it's giving me errors. I've followed the exact same steps given in the document. I'm on HDInsight 3.5, Storm 1.0.1.2.5.4.0-121

Here's the one for EventHubReader, as seen from the Storm UI.

```
com.microsoft.eventhubs.client.EventHubException: org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.ConnectionErrorException: An AMQP error occurred (condition='amqp:unauthorized-access'). TrackingId:53ca4652535f423e5f0049dc08ef9_G22, SystemTracker:gateway2, Timestamp:2/28/2017 7:51:21 AM
at com.microsoft.eventhubs.client.EventHubReceiver.ensureReceiverCreated(EventHubReceiver.java:112) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.eventhubs.client.EventHubReceiver.<init>(EventHubReceiver.java:65) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.eventhubs.client.EventHubConsumerGroup.createReceiver(EventHubConsumerGroup.java:56) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at com.microsoft.eventhubs.client.ResilientEventHubReceiver.initialize(ResilientEventHubReceiver.java:63) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.eventhubs.spout.EventHubReceiverImpl.open(EventHubReceiverImpl.java:74) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
...
AMQP error occurred (condition='amqp:unauthorized-access'). TrackingId:53ca4652535f423e825f0049dc08eff9_G22, SystemTracker:gateway2, Timestamp:2/28/2017 7:51:21 AM
at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Receiver.<init>(Receiver.java:223) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Session.createReceiver(Session.java:281) ~[stormjar.jar:?]  ... 11 more
```

EventHubWriter:

```
com.microsoft.eventhubs.client.EventHubException: An error occurred while sending data.
at com.microsoft.eventhubs.client.EventHubSender.sendCore(EventHubSender.java:93) ~[stormjar.jar:?] 
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender$SenderCreationException: Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target: my-event-hub
at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.<init>(Sender.java:191) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
 <storm.version>1.0.1</storm.version>
 <hadoop.version>2.7.3</hadoop.version>
</properties>
...
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
   <artifactId>eventhubs</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

I've made sure in my EventHubs.properties file the eventhub connection namespace and policy keys were correct. I've also opened the .jar artifact and made sure the EventHub classes were included.

Does anyone know how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case anyone else runs into the same problem. It turns out there's a bug with the storm eventhubs library.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2371?jql=project%20=%20STORM%20AND%20component%20=%20storm-eventhubs%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Unresolved%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC,%20key%20DESC